# error while installing m2e-wtp plugin for eclipse kepler

Tags: eclipse-plugin, m2e, eclipse-kepler, m2e-wtp

I have tried installing m2e-wtp plugin but getting below error:-

```
STDERR: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
 Software being installed: m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP 1.0.1.20130911-1545 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.20130911-1545)
 Software currently installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.3.0.20130129-0926 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.3.0.20130129-0926)
 Only one of the following can be installed at once:
  Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.jdt 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
  Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT 1.2.0.20120903-1050 (org.eclipse.m2e.jdt 1.2.0.20120903-1050)
  Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT 1.1.0.20120530-0009 (org.eclipse.m2e.jdt 1.1.0.20120530-0009)
  Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT 1.4.1.20140328-1905 (org.eclipse.m2e.jdt 1.4.1.20140328-1905)
  Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT 1.3.0.20130129-0926 (org.eclipse.m2e.jdt 1.3.0.20130129-0926)

Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.3.0.20130129-0926 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.3.0.20130129-0926)
  To: org.eclipse.m2e.jdt [1.3.0.20130129-0926]

Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP 1.0.1.20130911-1545 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp 1.0.1.20130911-1545)
  To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.jdt [1.4.0,2.0.0)

Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP 1.0.1.20130911-1545 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.20130911-1545)
  To: org.eclipse.m2e.wtp [1.0.1.20130911-1545]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

You need to first install the correct version of m2e-eclipse plugin.

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4/1.4.1.20140328-1905/

Then installed the m2e-wtp plugin version:-

http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/kepler/1.0.0/1.0.1.20130911-1545/m2e-wtp-jpa/

and same as above link for m2e-wtp

This resolved the error.